# como separo una condicion de otra en lenguaje c

Tags: c, condiciones

Soy un poco nuevo en esto, voy a entrar a la universidad y quise practicar un poco. de momento he llegado hasta las estructuras condicionales, si no es mucha molestia podrían decirme cual es mi error

Aquí un poco de mi avance, he logrado hacerlo correr correctamente pero una condición se muestra con la otra y no se como hacer para que no se muestre y eso

```
    /* Programa para gimnasio XYZ para poder llevar el control de las inscripciones, para saber cuantos clientes son
hombres y mujeres y asignar precio dependiendo la edad */

#include <stdio.h>

 void main(){

  int sexo, monto, edad;
  int retired;


  printf (" Ingrese su edad: ");
  scanf ("%i", &edad);

  printf (" Ingrese su sexo, 1 si es hombre y 2 si es mujer : ");
  scanf ("%i", &sexo);

    if (sexo=1){
        if (edad=18){
            if (edad>=18 && edad<=25){
                printf ("El total a pagar sera: $53.50 ");
            }
        }

         if (edad=25)
           if (edad>=25 && edad <=61){
              printf("El total a pagar sera: $45 ");

        }






    }

 }
```

Comment: dentro de los condicionales usas el operador de asignacion "=" pero el que deberias usar es el de comparacion que es "==". Dentro de los ifs debes poner == en lugar de =

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (sexo=1){
```

En C, el operador `=` es el operador de **asignación**. Para realizar comparaciones debes usar el operador de comparación `==`

```
if (sexo == 1) {
```

Por otro lado, fíjate que los bucles están mal anidados:

```
if (edad==18){
    if (edad>=18 && edad<=25){
```

Es decir, si `edad` vale exactamente 18 está claro que también se va a cumplir la siguiente condición, `18 <= edad <= 25`. Sin embargo, si edad valiese cualquier otro valor entre 19 y 25 no pasaría el primer condicional, por lo que el contenido del segundo condicinal sería irrelevante.

Me inclino a pensar que lo que estabas intentando es lo siguiente:

```
if (sexo==1){
    if (edad>=18 && edad<=25){
        printf ("El total a pagar sera: $53.50 ");
    }
    else if (edad>25 && edad <=61){
        printf("El total a pagar sera: $45 ");
    }
```

Comment: Faltó la llave de cierre, no?

Comment: @Mateo no estaba en la pregunta ... es posible que el código no termine ahí